# Cannot save changes in Google Play developer Console

Tags: android, beta-testing, developer-console

I am trying to upload a new apk for Beta Testing.
When I press the button "Upload new APK to Beta" I get the warning:
"You have unsaved changes in this page. Do you want to leave without saving?" but there isn't button for saving.

Comment: Ahh, this is only warning. What happens, when you select `yes` ?

Comment: The upload failed ("We could not save your changes. Please try again")

Comment: Oh. Sometimes it gives me the same popup, but when I click yes - it shows the dialog where I can upload the file. You can try refreshing the page.

Comment: Thanks Ravi. It's working now.

Comment: @AviadNemet - wat made it work.. im facing a similar issue.